# Spyder does not show class instance variables in variable explorer during debugging python

Tags: spyder

I am using Spyder v2.2.5 IDE for programming python. While debugging my python code using pdb in spyder, the IDE does not show the class instance variable in Variable Explorer. It's getting difficult to check the variable values using print statement every-time.
Is there any way to check the class instance variable values during debugging?

Comment: For information, this issue is reported here : https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1887

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I did find a temporary solution.  Every class object has a dictionary associated with it that contains the assigned variables. It is a little annoying, but you can assign a global variable to be equal to that dictionary which can be viewed in Spyder's variable explorer.

```
import numpy as np 
class someClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1=10     #integer type
        self.var2=np.ones((3,3,3))  #numpy array type
        self.var3=[np.ones((2,2,4))*i for i in range(5)]  #list type (of numpy arrays)

b=someClass()
tempdict=b.__dict__  #Then look at this variable under the Variable explorer
```

You will need to update `tempdict` every time you change any of the variables, but this will work.

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary solution until they fix this, I am using local variables inside the method until the very end for debug. Use the same name, but without the "self." in front of it.

Right before the return statement, I assign the local variables to the "self." variable equivalent.

If I need the values of a prior, existing "self." variable during execution , then I assign it to a local variable in the beginning of the method.

After debug phase is complete, you can replace the locals with the proper class attribute.